# Is copy_to_user necessary with procfs?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, procfs

I always thought `copy_to_user` was necessary when the kernel writes to users via procfs.

I forgot to do it once though (and I used `snprintf`) and everything was working fine. Now that I noticed it, I have been searching. I found [this link](http://tali.admingilde.org/linux-docbook/procfs-guide/ch03.html#id2498149) that doesn't say `copy_to_user` is needed even though for the other section (kernel reading from user) it does say `copy_from_user` is necessary.

So, is the buffer provided to kernel module to write data (so user reads from it), in kernel space already? Is it true that you don't need `copy_to_user` when writing through procfs? Or have I been lucky not to get a crash?

Comment: Wihtout seeing your actual code it's hard to tell. I suspect the copy_to_user part is done by the procfs machinery when the buffer is read.

Comment: @stsquad, that was my suspicion too, but I was surprised at that. I mean, if the kernel does the `copy_to_user`, why does it even exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use `copy_from_user` and `copy_to_user` when dealing with user space pointers. Even if simple `memcpy` sometimes works for you there are situations where it can fail. See [this](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0512.0/0513.html) thread for the information.

Speaking about `procfs` it's necessary to take into account that it use a little trick with kernel memory preallocation. See [this](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.3.1/fs/proc/generic.c#L42) link for details.

Comment: Thanks! The link to the /proc reader was really helpful and the discussion is quite interesting

Comment: FYI, `copy_to_user` always failed for me. In a case as simple as `char str[7] = "ABCDEF"; ret = copy_to_user(page + offset, str, 7);` it always returned `7`. The thing is, according to the same code you pointed me to, I indeed don't get a user pointer, but I always thought `copy_to_user` would understand and ignore kernel pointers. Nevertheless, the kernel explicitly calls `copy_to_user` itself, so I was forced to remove it.